# how to convert a Series of arrays into a single matrix in pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, multidimensional-array, series

I somehow got a `pandas.Series` which contains a bunch of arrays in it, as the `s` in the code below.

```
data = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[2,3,4],
        [3,4,5],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
s = pd.Series(data = data)
s.shape # output ---> (11L,)
# try to convert s to matrix
sm = s.as_matrix()
# but...
sm.shape # output ---> (11L,)
```

How can I convert the `s` into a matrix with shape (11,3)? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you going through a series? Why not directly convert to a matrix if that's what you want?

Comment: How about `import numpy as np; np.array(data)`? You may not need to make a `Series`. Also, note that a `(11,3)` dimension is better represented with `DataFrame`.

Comment: And your Series contains lists, not arrays.

Comment: @Abdou You don't even need `reshape`, just `np.array(data)` should work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If, for some reason, you have found yourself with that abomination of a `Series`, getting it back into the sort of `matrix` or `array` you want is straightforward:

```
In [16]: s
Out[16]:
0     [1, 2, 3]
1     [2, 3, 4]
2     [3, 4, 5]
3     [2, 3, 4]
4     [3, 4, 5]
5     [2, 3, 4]
6     [3, 4, 5]
7     [2, 3, 4]
8     [3, 4, 5]
9     [2, 3, 4]
10    [3, 4, 5]
dtype: object

In [17]: sm = np.array(s.tolist())

In [18]: sm
Out[18]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [19]: sm.shape
Out[19]: (11, 3)
```

But unless it's something you can't change, having that Series makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, I had a pandas series which was a series of rows, this helped me convert in to proper array dimensions (m,n) from (m, 1)

Answer (score 53):

Another way is to extract the values of your series and use numpy.stack on them.

```
np.stack(s.values)
```

PS. I've run into similar situations often.

Comment: This. Please this is the answer.

Comment: This is the way to go. Other methods ran out of memory on a 750GB RAM machine.

Comment: works on multi-dimensional arrays appended in a series (1000,) -> (1000, 128, 128, 3)

Answer (score 2):

I tested above methods with 5793 of 100D vectors. The old method, converting to list first, is fastest.

```py
%time print(np.stack(df.features.values).shape)
%time print(np.stack(df.features.to_numpy()).shape)
%time print(np.array(df.features.tolist()).shape)
%time print(np.array(list(df.features)).shape)
```

Result

```
(5793, 100)
CPU times: user 11.7 ms, sys: 3.42 ms, total: 15.1 ms
Wall time: 22.7 ms
(5793, 100)
CPU times: user 11.1 ms, sys: 137 µs, total: 11.3 ms
Wall time: 11.9 ms
(5793, 100)
CPU times: user 5.96 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 5.96 ms
Wall time: 6.91 ms
(5793, 100)
CPU times: user 5.74 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 5.74 ms
Wall time: 6.43 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

For the pandas>=0.24, you can also `np.stack(s.to_numpy())` or `np.concatenate(s.to_numpy())`, depending on your requirement.