# Changing shapes of PyTorch tensors and numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, word-embedding

I'm using CLIP model from huggingface to generate image embeddings, and I'm struggling with the output's shape.

I'm trying to get a numpy array of shape (n, 512) - given n samples and 512 is the embedding size of the CLIP model. However, I'm getting an array shape (n,) with each element is of shape (512,).

I have been trying to play with different function like squeeze, reshape, etc but nothing have worked so far.

This is my code to generate a Series of embeddings for a given df with images' URLs:

```
# initialize model and processor:
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model_ID = "openai/clip-vit-base-patch32"
# Save the model to device
model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained(model_ID).to(device)
# Get the processor
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(model_ID)

# create image embedding
def embed_url_img(img_url):
    """ Create embeddings for a given image URL """
    inputs = processor(images = Image.open(urlopen(img_url)),
                       return_tensors="pt"
                       )["pixel_values"].to(device)
    return model.get_image_features(inputs).squeeze(0).cpu().detach().numpy()

df['embeddings'] = df['url'].apply(embed_url_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

This post helped:
[how to convert a Series of arrays into a single matrix in pandas/numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824601/how-to-convert-a-series-of-arrays-into-a-single-matrix-in-pandas-numpy)

to transform the Series into a matrix:

`np.array(df['embeddings'].to_list())`